# how to change images on imageView after some interval

Tags: android

I have a problem that I want to paste images on ImageView in Android and that images are periodically changed after some interval. Means one by one images shown in ImageView. I am doing this with the help of Thread in java but I got some problem that Thread is not attached and something. Please review my code given below and tell me the exact error and how to remove that error or give me some diffrent way for doing this.

```
package com.ex.thread;

import com.ex.thread.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class thread extends Activity implements Runnable{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public static Integer[] mThumbIds = {

   R.drawable.al1,R.drawable.al2,R.drawable.al3,R.drawable.al4,

};
Thread th;
ImageView iv;
public void run()
{
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        iv.setImageResource(mThumbIds[i]);
        System.out.println("Sanat Pandey");
        try{
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
public void create()
{
    Thread th = new Thread(new thread());
    th.start();
    try{
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstace)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstace);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    create();
}
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't use things in the UI thread from a background one. So this call:

```
iv.setImageResource(mThumbIds[i]);
```

Has to be done in the main thread. In fact you probably don't need a background thread at all to get the effect you're looking for. You can make that just an activity, no need to implement runnable. and then do something like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yourImageViewID);
    int i = 0;
    Runnable r = Runnable(){
        public void run(){
             iv.setImageResource(mThumbIds[i]);
             i++;
             if(i >= mThumbIds.length){
                 i = 0;
             }
             iv.postDelayed(r, 3000); //set to go off again in 3 seconds.
         }
    };
    iv.postDelayed(r,3000); // set first time for 3 seconds
```

Comment: Sir, No any effect is generated after this new code. But No any error is found but it can't display any image.

Comment: sir, my debugger is not running run method of Runnable interface. why?

Comment: your solution works great thanx

i just wanted to know why did you use iv.postDelayed(r, 3000); twice (once inside the runnable and once outside)

Comment: you should type new to create a new object

Answer (score 35):

Try this..It works out well...

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);``
//
//
int []imageArray={R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2,R.drawable.img3};


final Handler handler = new Handler();
         Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            int i=0;
            public void run() {
                imageView.setImageResource(imageArray[i]);
                i++;
                if(i>imageArray.length-1)
                {
                i=0;    
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 50);  //for interval...
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000); //for initial delay..
    }
```

Comment: just reminded me to something.. how would u combine drawable resources (R.drawable.al1,R.drawable.al2,R.drawable.al3) with images stored in Internal storage in this example? any idea?

So I would like to show both kind of images randomly changed (from resources and internal storage).. 

10q

Comment: Make another list for ur internal storage images and call this list and int array of drawables alternatively.

Comment: That's what I came up with..Just thought there is some "cleaner" solution..

Currently I am checking if internal storage list is with at least one element and I am using it in that case, otherwise default resources list is used. I am having some troubles with List of URIs (content resolver inside adapter returns null o.O) but I will make it work.. ;) 

10q

Comment: Hi Piyush..tell me need any help?

Comment: Hi rekha ... need your help
I have done exactly you did but now I have to change some images on 6 imagesview with a regular interval of time.

Comment: Hey Avin, you mean you have 6 different imageView and each imageView should change images at a interval?

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
it's working

public class vv extends Activity {
    int b[] = {R.drawable.a, R.drawable.m, R.drawable.b, R.drawable.j, R.drawable.er, R.drawable.chan, R.drawable.vv};
    public ImageView i;
    int z = 0;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    i = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    i.setImageResource(b[0]);
    Thread timer = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(2000);

                for (z = 0; z < b.length + 2; z++) {
                    if (z < b.length) {
                        sleep(2000);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                i.setImageResource(b[z]);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        z = 0;

                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                System.out.println("finally");
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try this code.the images was saved in drawable. please do insert a imageview in xml code. noted that the time interval for the following code is 1 sec.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public ImageView iv;
public static Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.pic1,R.drawable.pic2,R.drawable.pic3,R.drawable.pic4};
int i;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    i=0;
    t.start();
}
Thread t = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (!isInterrupted()) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        iv.setImageResource(mThumbIds[i]);
                        i++;
                        if(i >= mThumbIds.length){
                            i = 0;
                        }}});}} 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }}};

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final int img[] = {R.drawable.flower1, R.drawable.flower2, R.drawable.flower3, R.drawable.flower4};

    layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);

    final Handler handler=new Handler();

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
           int i = 0;

            @Override
            public void run() {

                layout.setBackgroundResource(img[i]);
                i++;
                if (i > img.length - 1) {
                i = 0;
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 4000);  //for interval 4s..

            }
        };handler.postDelayed(runnable, 100); //for initial delay..

}
```

Comment: Could you give some explications ?