# Android ImageView show image onclick wait then show another image

Tags: java, android

I would like to show x image on `ImageView` `onClick` then wait and show y image. Currently I have I can get it to z image to start switch to y image but it skips x image for some reason.

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(z);

imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(x);
                try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                imageView.setImageBitmap(y);

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167541/how-to-change-images-on-imageview-after-some-interval, you have tried sleep main/UI thread that is incorrect,

Comment: use postDelayed instead in your UI.