# How to show two splash screen one by one in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-layout

I want to show two splash screens one by one. First to be aways static second will be change every time when user login. I do my second splash screen to change every time, but I dont know how to set a first static splash screen.

This is my .java file

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

public class SplashScreen extends DefaultActivity {

    int timeout = 2000; // Choose the delay (1000 = 1 second)

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        setFonts();
         // Randomise a background
        int[] yourListOfImages= {R.drawable.test, R.drawable.test1, R.drawable.test2, R.drawable.test3};

        Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        int posOfImage = random.nextInt(yourListOfImages.length);

        ImageView imageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(yourListOfImages[posOfImage]);
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Redirecting to the home page
                Intent redirect = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(redirect);
                finish();
            }
        }, timeout);
    }
}
```

and this is .xml fail

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    tools:context=".SplashScreen" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewSplash"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:tag="helvetica"
        android:text="@string/splash_intro" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You have to check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167541/how-to-change-images-on-imageview-after-some-interval