# how to display image on imageview dynamically from drawalble folder

Tags: android

```
public class Serchresult extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    ImageView imageView1;
    String Status;
    String Reason;
    TextView status;
    TextView reason;
    ImageView statusicon;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_serchresult);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Status = intent.getExtras().getString("Status");
        Reason = intent.getExtras().getString("Reason");
        imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.searchstatus_imgBack);
        imageView1.setOnClickListener(this);
        status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
        reason = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.reason);
        statusicon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        reason.setText(Reason.replace("null", ""));

        if (reason.equals("ACCEPTED")) {

            AQuery aq = new AQuery(getApplicationContext());
            statusicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.accept_icon);


        } else if (reason.equals("REJECTED")) {

            AQuery aq = new AQuery(getApplicationContext());
            statusicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.reject_icon);

        }

        else {
            // reason.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, null);
            statusicon.setImageResource(0);
        }
        status.setText(Status.replace("null", ""));

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v.getId() == R.id.searchstatus_imgBack) {
            finish();
        }

    }
}
```

here is my code i want display image from drawable folder accept and reject icon .i am getting   ACCEPTED and REJECTED from intent on the basis of this response i want to display image in image view i have apply condition but image is not visible please help me where am doing wrong

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167541/how-to-change-images-on-imageview-after-some-interval?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: i have to just display image  only 2 image on image view first accept image and reject image plz check

Comment: are you sure your if/elseif conditions are getting called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems working. But still you can try following code to display image. Make sure your `if-else` conditions are working

```
Bitmap defBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.accept_icon);
statusicon.setImageBitmap(defBitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `Bitmap` is too big for the heap, try use `BitmapFactory.Options` to reduce the size.

```
BitmapFactory.Options op = new BitmapFactory.Options();
op.inSampleSize = 4;
statusicon.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.accept_icon, op));
```